# UnsatisfiedLinkError for JNI on OSX with multiple C files

Tags: java, c, macos, gcc, java-native-interface

I've been able to make the JNI sample work on OSX with one C file, such as in [this tutorial](http://codingmaadi.blogspot.com/2012/08/jni-step-by-step-tutorial-on-os-x-with.html). But when I try to make a makefile that links in other C files, I get the dreaded "UnsatisfiedLinkError".

[Here's my makefile](https://github.com/ys1382/filagree/blob/master/makefile) in github.

Here's the result of typing "make java":

> gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG vm.c -o vm.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG struct.c -o struct.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG serial.c -o serial.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG compile.c -o compile.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG util.c -o util.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG sys.c -o sys.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG variable.c -o variable.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG interpret.c -o interpret.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG hal_stub.c -o hal_stub.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG node.c -o node.o
>   gcc -c -Wall -Os -std=gnu99 -I -fnested-functions -fms-extensions -DDEBUG file.c -o file.o
>   javac javagree.java
>  
>   javah -jni javagree
>   cc -c -fPIC -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers javagree.c -o libjavagree.o
>   libtool -dynamic -lSystem vm.o struct.o serial.o compile.o util.o sys.o variable.o interpret.o
>  hal_stub.o node.o file.o libjavagree.o -o libjavagree.dylib -macosx_version_min 10.8
>   
>   $ java javagree
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javagree.filagree(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)J
>       at javagree.filagree(Native Method)
>       at javagree.main(javagree.java:46)

The question is: why can't it find the function when I link in more files? Did I not link correctly?